# Taking data from HTML/JavaScript with PHP and adding to empty txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to take information taken from a HTML/JavaScript file and I want to add the data ($email = string, $vote = value from radio button) to an empty txt file using php.

What's wrong with my code? I don't think the foreach loop is being run. Thanks!

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$vote = $_REQUEST['player'];
$emailList = file('email.txt');
$voteList = file('votes.txt');

foreach ($emailList as $line => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
        file_put_contents("email.txt", $email."<br>", FILE_APPEND);
    } else if ($value == $email) {
        echo "You have already voted!";
    } else {
        file_put_contents("email.txt", $email."<br>", FILE_APPEND);
        echo "Your vote has been stored! Thanks.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foundMail = false;
foreach($emailList as $line => $value){
  if(trim(preg_replace('/\n/', '',$value)) == trim($email)) {
    $foundMail = true;
  }
}

if(!$foundMail) {
  file_put_content("email.txt", $email."\n", FILE_APPEND);
  echo ('your vote has been stored');
} else {
  echo 'you have allready voted';
}
```

Comment: Actually the email still gets added to the text file even though the email value is already in the text file.

Comment: Try to trim both $value and $email in your comparison statement - ```if(trim($value) == trim($email)) { .. ```